AWS Python Serverless Solution for WebSocket Client Needed
We are trying to receive event notifications from a website that has a WebSocket (wss://XXX) endpoint.  From the website API docs, the instructions are "Users must connect to the endpoint with a WebSocket client and then subscribe to any events that will trigger notifications."  We would like to do this through an AWS serverless solution as we have many other serverless apps deployed as it fits within our scope of development knowledge (which is half the battle always!! :))  We are a Python shop, so would like a Python serverless solution.
I have gone through several "server-side" WebSocket solution articles mentioning AWS IoT Core, API Gateway WebSocket APIS, etc and none of these are correct for setting up a client WebSocket "listener" solution.  I REALLY don't want to have to stand up an EC2 and pay all that $$ as a solution.
Is there any way to do this?
